# Adding element to list deletes previous elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i have a class with a constructor that returns objects. I'm adding these objects to a list but having trouble because every time i add a new element it replaces the previous ones with the current element that i am adding.

Here is the list and output:

```
    Objects a = new Objects("test1");
    Objects b = new Objects("test2");

    List<Objects> c = new ArrayList();

    c.add(a);
    c.add(b);
    System.out.println(c.get(0).getTest());
    System.out.println(c.get(1).getTest());
```

Here is the output:

```
test2
test2
```

Here is the class creating/returning the objects:

```
public class Objects
{
    public static String test;

    public Objects (String test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }

      public String getTest()
      {
          return test;
      }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `test` variable defined inside of `Objects`?

Comment: is this.test static???

Comment: provide the full source file you are using, given the error it is relevant to show it in extenso.

Comment: FYI it doesn't delete it. If it did your output would have be just test2 once. Attention to detail !

Comment: Thank you, i got rid of the static type on the test variable and its working now.

Comment: Remove static from here.

    public static String test;

use without static 

    public String test;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static is the problem here. Remove Static and it will work fine. Using statics like this example is not a good practice, read [here](http://blog.christianposta.com/testing/java-static-methods-can-be-a-code-smell/).

Answer (score 2):

remove the static in `Objects` for class member `test`:

```
public class Objects
{
    public String test;

    public Objects (String test)
    {
        this.test = test;
    }

      public String getTest()
      {
          return test;
      }
}
```

then you will get the desired output:

> Test1
>
> Test2

Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects. This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any object.

Answer (score 0):

Change `public static String test;` as `public String test;`

The `static` keyword in Java means that the variable or function is shared between all instances of that class as it belongs to the type, not the actual objects themselves.

So if you have a variable: `private static int i = 0;` and you increment it (`i++`) in one instance, the change will be reflected in all instances. i will now be 1 in all instances.

And [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String test;
```

This is the problem. `test` is class level variable, so you simply modify it, instead of creating a new one. Also, usually you make the variable private, and provide getter and setter to for the variable. That is called `encapsulation`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared `test` as static same variable will be used for all `Objects` instances. So its not overwriting the objects in the list . Its overwriting the value of `test`.

Solution :

> Remove static modifier
>   `public String test;`